# Modeling The Shunting-Yard Algorithm

Tags: c#, algorithm, oop, design-patterns

Background:

I am trying to implement a variant of the [Shunting-Yard Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm), but instead of outputting the expression in RPN notation, I'd like it to update itself as tokens are pushed in so that results can be displayed in real time (as if you were pressing buttons on a calculator and needed to update the display after each button).

Here is the Shunting-Yard class...

```
public class ShuntingYard
{
   private Stack<double> _operands;
   private Stack<Operation> _operations;

   public ShuntingYard()
   {
      this._operands = new Stack<double>();
      this._operations = new Stack<double>();
   }
}
```

And the `Operation` class would be something like...

```
public abstract class Operation
{
   public abstract void Evaluate(Stack<double> operands, Stack<Operation> operations);
}
```

The `Evaluate()` function updates the stacks accordingly, and the "current value" would be `_operands.Peek()`

Here are some of the "Operations" I have so far:

`public class NullaryOperation : Operation { }` 
E.g. Pi, e, etc. 
Just pushes constant onto `_operands`

`public class UnaryOperation : Operation { }` 
E.g. SquareRoot, Sine, Cosine, etc. 
Pops one number off of `_operands`, evaluates, and pushes result to `_operands`

`public class BinaryOperation : Operation { }` 
E.g. +, -, *, /, etc. 
Checks precedence, evaluates if needed, pushes result to `_operands`

---

Here is the problem: 
I need the ability to push open-parentheses `(` and closed-parentheses `)` onto the `_operations` stack as part of the algorithm.  Moreover, when I add a closed-parenthesis, I need to keep popping operands/operations until I encounter an open-parenthesis.

I want to avoid checks like this (checking object types):

`while (operations.Peek().GetType() != typeof(OpenParen)) { ... }`

I want to avoid adding a method like this in `Operation`:

`public abstract bool IsOpenParen();`

I could do something like this...

```
public abstract class Operation 
{
   public enum OperationType { Nullary, Unary, Binary, OpenParen, CloseParen };
   public abstract OperationType GetOperationType() { };

   public abstract void Evaluate(Stack<double> operands, Stack<Operation> operations);
}
```

But requiring all subtypes to specify their type as an enum seems like a bad design.

---

How should I model this in such a way that I can track and handle parentheses as they are pushed in?

On a side note: Thinking about parentheses as "Operations" doesn't seem to make much sense to me. However, the algorithm on Wikipedia treats them this way, and I can't think of any other way to keep track of their position relative to other "real" operations.

Thank you.

Comment: Any reason why you don't want to special-case handling parens in your design when you clearly need to special-case handling them in your application? I mean, I'm sure you *could* come up with some sort of abstract concept so it's not a special case anymore, but this sounds like overengineering unless you know there are more constructs you need to handle in a similar fashion.

Comment: Parenthesis are unnecessary in Polish notation, whether Forward or Reverse; they are only required in infix notation.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens The Shunting-Yard algorithm parses an infix notation expression. RPN is only one of its possible outputs.

Comment: Sounds like what you want is for every opening parenthesis to start its own `ShuntingYard` object. When you get the closing parenthesis, you can finish parsing that sequence and return to the prior sequence.

Comment: @millimoose I am not opposed to special-case handling, in fact, I believe there is probably no way around it. However, if possible, I'd like to avoid checking types at run-time (for portability reasons), and I'd prefer not to require every subsequent `Operation` to declare whether or not it's a parenthesis (if such requirements are possible).
--Edit: I see what you are saying. You're right, I may be over-engineering a bit. I'd still like to explore my options a little though, first.

Comment: @StarPilot I had this same idea, and it is beginning to look more attractive. Basically, keeping a Stack-of-Stacks every time a parenthesis is pushed.

Comment: @millimoose: The point of the stack in the Shunting-Yard algorithm is that it eliminates the need for handling parenthesis. The current stack-depth is exactly the number of (implied and explicit) parenthesis levels. An open-parenthesis is just a Push operation, and a closing parenthesis is just a Pop operation.

Comment: `Peek` is a non-trivial operation, if I understand correctly what you mean. Suppose the user enters `3*4+5`, which is `17`. What do you display when they type `*`? Then when they type `6`, you have to undo the addition to get `5` back, in order to multiply it with `6`; and then redo the addition to get `42`. In general, you might need to be prepared to unwind as much of the stack as you have precedence levels. There's a relatively simple solution to this problem using immutable datastructures, but its harder with c# mutable `stack`s.

Comment: @rici Yes, that's correct. I need to know what to display after each input. The sequence `1+2*3+4=` should display `1,1,2,2,3,7,4,11`. Having to unwind would be too much trouble for more complex operations, but should not be necessary using shunting-yard...you don't evaluate until the previous operator has a higher precedence (so, when the second + sign comes, the previous (* sign) has higher precedence, so it's evaluated. But if you enter `(1+2)*3+4=`, the sequence should be `0,1,1,2,3,3,3,9,9,4,13`

Comment: Showing the output like that can be highly confusing to the user... 1+ 2*3, we see a 3 and when the *3 appears it becomes a 7? What? Why not 9? :-)

Comment: @Knoothe From what I've seen, there are two types of calculator displays: Those that preserve order of operations, and those that don't. If you are using Windows, try typing `1+2*3+` on the Basic calculator and then on the Scientific calculator and see what you get. On Basic, you will get a `9`. On Scientific, you will get a `7`. I am choosing to implement the Scientific functionality. The actual display does not change until you press the `+` after the 3 (not "when the *3 appears...).

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Operand {
    private ShuntingYard sy;
    private double d;
    public Operand(double v) {
        d=v;
        sy=null;
    }
    public Operand() {
        d=NaN(); // I'm inept at C#, this should mean "d" is unused
        sy=new ShuntingYard();
    }
}
public class ShuntingYard {
    private Stack<Operand> _operands;
    private Stack<Operation> _operations;

   public ShuntingYard()
   {
      this._operands = new Stack<Operand>();
      this._operations = new Stack<Operation>();
   }
}
```

StarPilot gives a correct advice, putting another `ShuntingYard` into the stack, but the correct way is to put a `ShuntingYard` as an operand, not as an operation. Now, once a nested `ShuntingYard` appears, all subsequent operands and operations are passed to it. A preparation should be made in order for a `ShuntingYard` to receive a closing parenthesis operation, a top-level one should throw an error, and the inner ones should evaluate themselves and replace containing `Operand` with the result of its evaluation.